# Examples of state space models that can't be transformed into ARIMA models

Tags: time-series, arima, seasonality, kalman-filter, state-space-models

As my question illustrates, we know the state space model (SSM) is more general compared with ARIMA, and every ARIMA model could be transformed into a state space form, and some SSMs could be transformed into ARIMA as well, like the local linear trend model could be viewed as an approximate of ARIMA(0,2,2).  [This question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/78287/what-are-disadvantages-of-state-space-models-and-kalman-filter-for-time-series-m) has talked about the difference of SSMs and ARIMA before.

Generally speaking, I am wondering **which kind of SSMs can not be transformed into an ARIMA model** or you may give me some examples. I came up with one example, the pseudo-additive structural time series model (gaussian noises), but not very sure whether it is correct.
$$
y_t=T_t(S_t+I_t-1)
$$
$$
T_{t+1} = T_t + \eta_t
$$
$$
S_t= -\sum_{i=1}^{s-1} S_{t-i} + \omega_t
$$

More strictly, are there any **linear** SSMs that don't have corresponding ARIMA forms?

Thanks :)

Comment: This [question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/178937/find-state-space-model-to-compare-with-box-jenkins-arima-model/178950) has talked about the case of how to transform a SSM to ARIMA. But I want some counter-example here... Anyone knows?