# Does this state space model make sense?

Tags: time-series, self-study, arima, state-space-models

I'm working on a problem,

> Consider that a times series $\{y_t\}$ is generated from an $\text{ARIMA}(1,1,1)$ model, so that $$y_t-y_{t-1}=\alpha(y_{t-1}-y_{t-2})+\epsilon_t+\gamma\epsilon_{t-1},$$ where $\alpha$ is the AR parameter, $\gamma$ is the MA parameter and $\{\epsilon_t\}$ is a Gaussian white noise sequence with variance equal to $1$. Define the state space vector $$\beta_t=\begin{bmatrix}y_t\\y_{t-1}\\\epsilon_t\end{bmatrix}.$$ Write down a state space representation for $y_t$, i.e. express $y_t$ as a state space model: $$y_t=x^T\beta_t+\delta_t,\\\beta_t=F\beta_{t-1}+\zeta_t,$$ specifying $x,F,\delta_t$ and $\zeta_t$, and writing down the distributions of $\delta_t$ and $\zeta_t$.

I get
\begin{align}
y_t
& = (1+\alpha)y_{t-1} - \alpha y_{t-2} + \epsilon_t-\gamma\epsilon_{t-1} \\
& = \begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}y_t\\y_{t-1}\\\epsilon_t\end{bmatrix}+0 \\
& = x^T\beta_t+\delta_t \text{ where } x=\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\end{bmatrix}, \hspace{1em} \delta_t\sim N(0,0); \\[1.5em]
\beta_t
& = \begin{bmatrix}y_t\\y_{t-1}\\\epsilon_t\end{bmatrix} \\
& = \begin{bmatrix}1+\alpha&-\alpha&\gamma\\1&0&0\\-(1+\alpha)&\alpha&-\gamma\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}y_{t-1}\\y_{t-2}\\\epsilon_{t-1}\end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix}\epsilon_t\\0\\y_t\end{bmatrix} \\
& = F\beta_{t-1}+\zeta_t \text{ where } F=\begin{bmatrix}1+\alpha&-\alpha&\gamma\\1&0&0\\-(1+\alpha)&\alpha&-\gamma\end{bmatrix},\hspace{1em}\zeta_t\sim N\left(\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\\hat{y}_t\end{bmatrix},Z\right).
\end{align}

Something seems to have  gone wrong. I don't know how I can specify the transitional covariance matrix $Z$; I don't think $\hat{y}$ is allowable as a mean at this stage in the calculation; and I'm suspicious about the observation model containing $y_t$ in the parameter vector $\beta$ and the transition model containing it as part of $\zeta_t$.

I notice the model is very similar to the one [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/605841/285236), but the latter doesn't have $y_t$ in the $\beta$ equivalent.

Could someone give me a pointer?

Comment: I don't know of a general approach when you have differences. But there are general approaches when the data is not differenced. The document at the link below gives a pretty brief overview but, if you want details, Hamilton is probably your best bet. Andrew Harvey's blue text might contain some material. Kohn and Ansley wrote a paper on it but I haven't been able to track it down. If I find it, I'll post another comment. http://www-stat.wharton.upenn.edu/~stine/stat910/lectures/14_state_space.pdf

Comment: Regretfully, my comment above seems to be wrong. With further investigation, there do exist general approaches even with differences. The first page of this link gives three references on converting from arima to state space. hopefully, one of those might help.  https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82606719.pdf